# How to show a row for the dates not in records of a table as zero

Tags: sql

I am trying to show the records as zero for the dates not found.

Below is my basic query:

```
Select date_col, count(distinct file_col), count(*) from tab1
where date_col between 'date1' and 'date2'
group by date_col;
```

The output is for one date.

I want all the dates to be shown in result.

Comment: Which database are you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to deal with this type of problem is to use something called a *calendar* table.  This calendar table contains all the dates which you want to appear in your report.  We can create a crude one by using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.file_col) AS d_cnt,
    COUNT(t2.file_col) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-06-01' AS date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-06-02' UNION ALL
    ...
) t1
LEFT JOIN tab1 t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date_col
WHERE
    t1.date BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
GROUP BY
    t1.date;
```

Critical here is that we left join the calendar table to your table containing the actual data, but we count a column in your data table.  This means that zero would be reported for any day not having matching data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgreSQL, you could generate series with necessary dates period.

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.file_col) AS d_cnt,
    COUNT(t2.file_col) AS cnt
FROM
(
  select to_char( '?'::DATE + (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,11)),'yyyy-mm-dd')as month) x
    ...
) t1
LEFT JOIN tab1 t2
    ON t1.date = to_char(t2.date_col,'yyyy-mm')
WHERE
    t1.date BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
GROUP BY
    t1.date;
```

In this example show how to generate sequence for month period.